# What does the abbreviation "SNT" and "MNT" in telc language tests mean?

Tags: abbreviation

For example, in http://www.ehrstein.de/bilder/telc-Uebungstests/telc_deutsch_c1_hochschule_uebungstest1.pdf

I can see:

[image]

Was bedeutet "SNT" und "MNT" hier?

Comment: @Janka, warum schreibst du das nicht als antwort?

Answer (score 1):

These are the marks for oral test (**MNT**) and written test (**SNT**)

**Note** **mündlich** und **schriftlich**

(look at page 46 in pdf above)

Comment: I don't see it in page 46 of the PDF

Comment: page down:
Teilergebnis I (Schriftliche Prüfung)
Teilergebnis II (Mündliche Prüfung)
166
 48
 77,5%
 22,5%
Gesamtpunktzahl 214 100%

Comment: And what is the "S", "Q", and "P"?

Comment: @MartinThoma "S" and "P" are probably "Summe" and "Prozent". No clue about the "Q" tbh.

Comment: Q could be a Quantile.

Comment: yes, I thought this was clear ;)